# OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')") What is causing this error?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, networking, binance, py-telegram-bot-api

I am developing an automated trading program.

I am using python-binance and telepot.

At first, after a certain amount of time, I thought that an OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')") error would occur when sometimes making a transaction request to Binance.

However, if you look at the recent error section, an error occurred in the telegram message transmission part.

I am currently using python 3.8.10 version on ubuntu 20.04 LTS version OS on GCP instance.

What is the cause of the error itself?

As with most answers found in searches, I have tried adding the http header and making a new connection, but the error itself continues to occur.

I am curious as to the cause of this error itself.

Comment: 1. One of the peers closed the connection without having read all the inbound data. 2. One of the peers deliberately reset the connection by closing it abortively. 3. One of the peer hosts reset the connection due to the owning process exiting or a network error. 4. ...

Comment: Automated trading applications must be as fast as possible. Python is far too slow for such an application. You really need a very fast processor running native code, else you will be at great disadvantage compared to other traders.